# Boot hangs on splash screen in 20.04

Tags: boot, grub2, dell, plymouth

I have installed 20.04 on a Dell OptiPlex 7050, with an Intel HD Graphics 630 (rev 04).

The boot process hangs on the splash screen. This does not happen on the first reboot immediately after installation, but on the next boot after that.

I have some partial solutions by adjusting the line GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT in /etc/default/grub:

1. Use 'nomodeset' in addition to the default 'quiet splash'. The system boots with the splash screen, but this
   option seems to disable some graphics functionality permanently
   (not just during the boot): after booting with 'nomodeset', all
   compositor animations in gnome-shell are disabled.
2. Replace 'quiet splash' with 'nosplash'. This works better: the
   system is both able to boot, and composting animations work. The
   only downside is that you don't have a splash screen.

Question: It should be possible to have both a splash screen during
boot, and working gnome-shell animations. How can this be achieved?

(Personally, I don't really care about the splash screen, but this
problem cost me enough time and headache that I wanted to post
something for others.)

Answer (score -1):

You should try this:

1. Log in to recovery mode and then 'resume'
2. Edit `/etc/default/grub`, change the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` so that: `"quiet splash"` becomes `"dis_ucode_ldr quiet splash"`
3. Run: `sudo update-grub`

Hopefully, this works for you.

Comment: You should really say what this does as it is rarely a good idea to use this parameter permanently. This parameter disables microcode (firmware) updates which normally happen on every boot. While microcode updates can very occasionally cause boot problems, they are important for security. See https://wiki.debian.org/Microcode. If someone tries this and finds it does not work, they should revert it. If it does work, they should try to revert it periodically to see if the bug got fixed.